# Project couldn't be created in SageMaker MLOps Project Walkthrough Using Third-party Git Repos in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, mlops

i tried to SageMaker MLOps Project Walkthrough Using Third-party Git Repos using AWS pipline. I am begginer in AWS. This is errror.

**"Your project couldn't be created
Studio encountered an error when creating your project. Try recreating the project again.
Resource creation cancelled
"**

What can i do for this?

Here is image of it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVhVk.jpg)

Comment: Can you retry creating the project? Does it still error out? Also, you can go to CloudFormation and there should be a stack starting with SC- (projects are provisioned through CloudFormation templates). You can check if there is an error in the template, through the Events tab. That would help in narrowing down your error.